# Getting each example exactly once

Tags: tensorflow

For monitoring my model's performance on my evaluation dataset, I'm using `tf.train.string_input_producer` for the filenames queue on .tfr files, then I feed the parsed examples to the `tf.train.batch` function, that produces batches of a fixed size.

Assume my evaluation dataset contains exactly 761 examples (a prime number). To read all the examples exactly once, I have to have a batch size that divides 761, but there is no such, except 1 that will be too slow and 761 that will not fit in my GPU. Any standard way for reading each example exactly once?

Actually, my dataset size is not 761, but there is no number in the reasonable range of 50-300 that divides it exactly. Also I'm working with many different datasets, and finding a number that approximately divides the number of examples in each dataset can be a hassle.

Note that using the `num_epochs` parameter to `tf.train.string_input_producer` does not solve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reader.read_up_to` as in [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4addf4b5806cd731949c6582a83f5824599cd1ef/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/graph_io.py#L183). Your last batch will be smaller, so you need to make sure your network doesn't hard-wire batch-size anywhere